# Suspicious activity on antivirus detecting port scans

Tags: ip, port, anti-virus

Within 3 hours Bitdefender blocked 4 port scans of different IPs and Countries...I don't know what's happening. Can anyone suggest me what's going on?

These are the IPs blocked!

```
197.89.232.231
121.54.54.250
173.32.41.59
76.20.94.47
```

This was while I was writing this post!

```
180.191.105.86
```

Comment: more and more scan attacks are blocked continuously!

Comment: Are you using a modem/router? Such scans are normally blocked by the router firewall.

Comment: look up those ip's using this page   http://ipaddress.com/reverse-ip/

Answer (score 0):

In theory anyone can perform a port scan. It doesn't mean you have a virus infection, malware, or so. There are thousands of bots on the net that will get IP address blocks (either by trying randonmly or because of massive lists on some obscure websites) and perform port scans, in order to try to detect potentially dangerous open ports.

Then they would possibly try to either run brute force attacks or try to exploit some vulnerability.

The scans themselves do not harm, so don't worry about that.

Comment: yeah Thanks! But my antivirus never showed like this blocks and only today its showing lots of scan, made me scared of boing hacked!

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. Probably someone picked your IP and is trying to find out some vulnerability or potentially dangerous ports open, but if you're not running some risky software/daemons on them you don't have to worry about that (especially if the antivirus blocks those attempts).